# Any way to import/export to multiple tables from one csv?

Tags: python, mysql, csv, django-admin, django-import-export

I am trying to create an import/export flow that spans multiple tables.
For example, let's say this is my csv file

"id | question_text | answer_1 | answer_2| answer_3| correct_answer"

And I have two tables: 'Questions' and 'Answers' , such that answer points to question and stores the answer text plus whether its correct or not, while question just has the text and id.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what technology that you are using.Try using BCP function.
Copy 2 table value into a single temp table and use bcp out option

Comment: hi @karthick i am using django import and export with that i am importing bulk data into db and now i have to split the inserted data into 3 different tables